# array of array of strings in c program

Tags: arrays, c, string, multidimensional-array

It seems I'm confused with how to use array of strings in c code.
Here, what I wanted to do is making a master_array which includes all other array of strings in.

I made a code like below.
And the output is

```
 arr1[1] = pear
 arr2[1] = lettuce
 arr3[1] = Smith
 master_array[1][2] = onion
 sizeof(arr1) = 4
 sizeof(master_array[0]) = 1
```

Except for the last one, everything was as expected.
I expected sizeof(master_array[0]) = 4.
But the result was 1.

Would someone point out what I am confused with?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   char *arr1[] = {"apple", "pear", "banana", "melon"};
   char *arr2[] = {"carrot", "lettuce", "onion", "spinach"};
   char *arr3[] = {"Tom", "Smith", "Dave", "John"};
   char **master_array[] = {arr1, arr2, arr3};

   printf("arr1[1] = %s\n", arr1[1]);
   printf("arr2[1] = %s\n", arr2[1]);
   printf("arr3[1] = %s\n", arr3[1]);
   printf("master_array[1][2] = %s\n", master_array[1][2]);

   printf("sizeof(arr1) = %ld\n", sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(char *));
   printf("sizeof(master_array[0]) = %ld\n", sizeof(master_array[0])/sizeof(char *));

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I found one line missing. Now it has everything.

Answer (score 1):

`arr1` has a type of `char*[4]`.

However, `master_array[0]` has a type of `char **`, not `char*[4]`.

Comment: Does it mean I cannot get the number of elements of sub array using master_array?

Comment: Correct, you cannot figure out the size of an array unless it is statically allocated, and you use the literal name of that variable.  Because everywhere else, an array is just a pointer to the first element.

Answer (score 1):

This line misleads:

`printf("sizeof(master_array[0]) = %ld\n", sizeof(master_array[0])/sizeof(char *));`

Because it says it is printing sizeof `master_array[0]` but is isn't.  It is printing size of `master_array[0] / sizeof(char *)`.

It helps to realize that C doesn't really have strings - instead String functions expect a pointer to the first character of a string, and for the string to be terminated with the null character (byte value 0).